# Почему не работает скрипт?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Имеется скрипт:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('table.values tr').click(function () {
$.get("/Task/Edit/", {TaskId: $(this).find('input.rowID').val()
        });
    });
});
```

В скрипт передается значение, из скрытого поля в aspx-файле:

```html
<input type="hidden" class="rowID" value="<%=t.TaskId%>"/>
```

Как сделать, чтобы после отработки скрипта строка выглядела следующим образом:

```
/Task/Edit/число из скрытого поля
```

Что в этом скрипте означает **TaskId:** ?

Comment: А как сделать что-бы запрос осуществлялся не на страницу index.php а edit.aspx в папке /Task/ ?

Comment: $.post("/Task/edit.aspx", {....}); И кстати, index.php - я просто предположил. Если на сайте используется ЧПУ, то файл-обработчик может быть и edit.aspx, даже при указанном изначально пути "/Task/Edit/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего TaskId это параметр который будет передаваться в метод контроллера, его нужно было заменить на Id.

Заработал такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('table.values tr').bind('click', function () {
    var taskID = $(this).find('input.rowID').val();
    $.get("/Task/Edit/", { id: taskID }, function () {
      document.location.href = '/Task/Edit/' + taskID;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- `$('table.values tr').click();` // По клику на <tr> в таблице с классом values,
- `$(this).find('input.rowID').val();` // Выхватывает значение из поля (input) с классом .rowID,
- `$.post()` // Осуществляет запрос методом POST на страницу (index.php), находящуюся по следующему пути: "/Task/Edit/", отправляя данные, взятые из поля 'input.rowID'

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь поле input:hidden находится в той же строке (в тэге tr), по которому происходит нажатие. Иначе как минимум вы не получите своего значения, а получите undefined.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" class="rowID" value="<%=t.TaskId%>"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Чтобы адрес для отправления выглядел "/Task/Edit/8", тогда вам надо не $.post использовать, а $.get и добавлять к адресу получаемое значение из скрытого поля ("/Task/Edit/" + $(this).find('input.rowID').val())

[jQuery.get() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)